# How to remove multiple lines from file in bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am adding several lines to a file like this:

```
 echo "server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  ${brand}.mydomain.com;
    root         /srv/www/clients/${brand}/soon;
 }" >> default
```

The result is like this (brand is passed via parameter) :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  cola.mydoman.com;
    root         /srv/www/clients/cola/soon;
 }
```

The question is how to remove this specifically if this file contains lots of similar other values. Is it possible to do this with sed, awk or something else?

Comment: basically you want to check if the file already has a `server{...}` block and replace it with a new one?

Comment: `bash` is not a data processing language. Use a language with proper data structures, parse the configuration file, make changes in memory, and write changes back to the original (which is probably easiest by overwriting the original altogether with a complete in-memory image.)

Comment: Agree that `bash/sed` is not what you want to use, but you really need to include a small sample input along with sample output from that input. I can think of at least 3 interpretations of "lots of similar other values." Good luck.